# Storing/Saving user's question and bot's response using AWS Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have created a bot using the AWS console. I am looking for capabilities in AWS Lex for me to store the chat conversations. Currently, I could see just the Bot's response shown on the console. How do I capture the user's query in the first place.

Below is the response capture on the AWS lex console. The 'message' shown in the response from the bot. But the users query - "tell me more about the company" is not captured here.

```
    RequestID: ac7be9e5-xxxxx
{
  "dialogState": "Fulfilled",
  "intentName": "Aboutus",
  "message": "Here is the information you are looking for: https://demo/about-us/",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "slotToElicit": null,
  "slots": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using an AWS Lambda function as a code hook for your bot. The [event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-input-event-format) passed to the lambda contains the `inputTranscript` and all other metadata about the state of the interaction. Your lambda function can take whatever action is needed to log the interaction (update DynamoDB, send a message to SQS, etc).

Comment: Is there a feature in Lex console where we can use the lambda function and download/export the whole conversation? If not, I would have to write a script to capture the `inputTranscript` and save it separately?

Comment: Yes, you will need to write custom code to handle this